# Geometric Brownian Motion Properties

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I was reading *Oksendal's* book "*Stochastic Differential Equations*", *fifth Ed., pp. 62-63* and came across some counter-intuitive properties of the Geometric Brownian motion (GBM).

Let $\alpha,r>0$ and $B_t$ a Brownian motion. Then, the GBM 
$$N_t=N_0 \exp((r-\alpha^2/2) t+\alpha B_t)$$
is the solution of the SDE
$$dN_t=rN_tdt+\alpha N_tdB_t$$
It is proved (page 63) that
$$E[N_t]=E[N_0] e^{rt}$$
which means that the mean of the process is exponentially increasing over time for $r>0$. On the other hand, if $r<\alpha^2/2$ it is proved that
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}N_t=0 \qquad a.s.$$

These two properties seem intuitively contradictory (the **mean increases exponentially over time** but at the same time **the process converges to zero a.s.**). I was wandering if someone can provide some physical explanation on this.

Also, a follow up question: For $0<r<\alpha^2/2$  is **the solution bounded a.s. or bounded in the mean**?

Comment: For a sequence of positive random variables such that $X_n\to0$ almost surely and yet, $E(X_n)\to\infty$, try $P(X_n=n^4)=1/n^2$, $P(X_n=1/n^2)=1-1/n^2$ for every $n\geqslant1$.

Comment: @Did Thank you. So this actually means that as $t$ grows to infinity the probability of $N_t$ taking large values goes to zero with a slower rate. What does this imply for the actual realization of the process? What will we observe in simulations?

Comment: In the example in my comment, after a while, each $X_n$ equals $1/n^2$ (but beware that "after a while" means here, "for every $n\geqslant N$ for some random, almost surely finite $N$").

Answer (score 0):

I think the limit

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}N_t=0 \qquad a.s.$$

is clear since by iterated law of the logarithm the Brownian motion grows much closer than linear ($\sqrt{t\log\log t}$) and so it just says that the negative linear drift beats it.

In the computation

$$N_t=N_0 \exp((r-\alpha^2/2) t+\alpha B_t)$$

we use that $B_{t}\sim N(0,t)$. But as you know with Gaussians, most of the mass is concentrated near the mean and it reaches $\pm t$ with increasingly small probability. So that is why most of the actual paths that you simulate will behave according to the zero-limit, the same that sampling from a Gaussian mostly gives points centered around zero.

> Also, a follow up question: For $0<r<\alpha^2/2$  is **the solution bounded a.s. or bounded in the mean**?

The mean is unbounded as you just computed. The solution is not necessarily bounded for *finite* time. The limit just says that eventually it goes to zero after some *random* time.

Even in the case of $r=0$ from here  [Density of first hitting time of Brownian motion with drift](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053294/density-of-first-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion-with-drift) we have that the density of hitting any level $a>0$ is positive. See here too [Geometric Brownian Motion Probability of hitting uper boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268438/geometric-brownian-motion-probability-of-hitting-uper-boundary).