# Applying the Girsanov to use the reflection principle

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion

I would like to compute the probability of a Geometric Brownian motion exceeding a certain value somewhere in a given period.
We define the process by
\begin{align*}
    d S_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t dWt,
\end{align*}
and using Itô's lemma we find the following solution
\begin{align*}
    S_t = S_0 e^{(\mu -  \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)t + \sigma W_t},
\end{align*}
Where $W_t$ denotes a Wiener process.
Now we want to compute the probability of $S_t$ exceeding $B>S_0$ for some $t\in(0,T]$.
We may now write
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}\left(\exists t\in(0,T]: S_t \geq B \right) &= \mathbb{P}\left(\max_{0<t\leq T} S_t \geq B \right)\\
    &= \mathbb{P}\left(\max_{0<t\leq T}S_0 e^{(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W_t} \geq B \right)\\
    &= \mathbb{P}\left(\max_{0<t\leq T}(\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)t+\sigma W_t \geq \ln \frac{B}{S_0} \right)
\end{align*}
So far so good. But now I would like to apply the reflection principle. But this may only be applied to a Wiener process, which is not the case if we set the drift of our GBM to 0, that is $\mu=0$.

To work around this problem I figured that I should apply the Girsanov theorem to make this a pure Wiener process. The problem here is that I don't know how to apply it. This is what I tried:

First we set $\nu=\frac{\mu}{\sigma}-\frac{\sigma}{2}$, then Girsanov tells us that there exists a probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{Q}(\omega) = e^{-\nu W_t^\mathbb{P}-\frac{\nu^2}{2}t}\mathbb{P}(\omega),
\end{equation*}
*(Which I didn't really understand, as it seems that the new measure depends on a random variable)*

such that
\begin{equation*}
W_t^{\mathbb{Q}} = \nu t + W_t^\mathbb{P}
\end{equation*}
is a Wiener process under $\mathbb{Q}$. *(Note that $W_t^\mathbb{P}$ denotes our original Wiener process)*

Then we find that
\begin{align*}
dW_t^\mathbb{P} = dW_t^\mathbb{Q} - (\frac{\mu}{\sigma} - \frac{\sigma}{2})dt.
\end{align*}
Substituting this in or differential equation gives
\begin{align*}
dS_t &= \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t(dW_t^\mathbb{Q}-(\frac{\mu}{\sigma} - \frac{\sigma}{2})dt)= \frac{\sigma^2}{2}S_tdt + \sigma S_t dW_t^\mathbb{Q}.
\end{align*}
And using Itô's lemma now gives the solution
\begin{equation*}
S_t = S_0e^{\sigma W_t^\mathbb{Q}}.
\end{equation*}
Thus under the $\mathbb{Q}$ measure we can apply the reflection principle:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Q}\left(\exists t\in(0,T]: S_t \geq B \right) &= \mathbb{Q}\left(\max_{0<t\leq T}\sigma W_t^\mathbb{Q} \geq \ln \frac{B}{S_0}\right)\\
&= 2\mathbb{Q}\left(\sigma W_T^\mathbb{Q} \geq \ln \frac{B}{S_0}\right).
\end{align*}
And finally we can translate this between $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ to get
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left(\exists t\in(0,T]: S_t \geq B \right) &= e^{\nu W_t^\mathbb{P}+\frac{\nu^2}{2}t}\mathbb{Q}\left(\exists t\in(0,T]: S_t \geq B \right)\\
&= e^{\nu W_t^\mathbb{P}+\frac{\nu^2}{2}t}2\mathbb{Q}\left(\sigma W_T^\mathbb{Q} \geq \ln \frac{B}{S_0}\right)\\
&= 2\mathbb{P}\left(\sigma W_T^\mathbb{Q} \geq \ln \frac{B}{S_0}\right)\\
&= 2\mathbb{P}\left(W_T^\mathbb{P} \geq \ln \frac{\frac{B}{S_0}-(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T}{\sigma}\right)
\end{align*}
But this is just the same as applying the reflection principle on $(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+\sigma W_t^\mathbb{P}$ which isn't allowed in general.

I know for sure that the last steps are incorrect because it would imply that you can use the reflection principle regardless, but I'm not sure if I have made mistakes along the way.
I would really appreciate someone pointing out my mistake to me and showing me the correct way to implement the Girsanov theorem.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit: I would like to refer to this answered question for a closed formula answer.
[Geometric Brownian Motion Probability of hitting uper boundary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268438/geometric-brownian-motion-probability-of-hitting-uper-boundary?rq=1)
However I must confess that I still don't understand what is happening here.

Also apparently this method is described in "Brownian motion and stochastic calculus"
by Ioannis Karatzas, Steven E. Shreve according to another article I read
*