# Hitting time of a drifted Brownian motion: Exponential decay in time.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion and for $\alpha>0$ consider the drifted Brownian motion 
\begin{align*}
X_t=\alpha B_t+\alpha^2 t,\quad t\geq 0.
\end{align*}
Is there a simple way to show that for the first passage time 
\begin{align*}
T=\inf\{t\geq 0: X_t\geq h\},
\end{align*}
where $h>0$, the probability $\mathbb{P}(T>t)$ decays exponentially as $t\to\infty$?

More generally, can this be extended to Ito diffusions of the form
\begin{align}
Y_t=\int_0^t\alpha_s dB_s+\int_0^t\alpha_s^2 ds,\quad t\geq 0,
\end{align}
where we can assume that $\alpha_t\in[a,b]$ with $0<a<b<\infty$. Clearly in this case, $(Y_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a time-changed drifted Brownian motion: 
\begin{align*}
Y_t = W_{\langle Y\rangle_t} + \langle Y\rangle_t,\quad t\geq 0
\end{align*}
where $(W_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a Brownian motion.

See also [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053294/density-of-first-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion-with-drift): [Density of first hitting time of Brownian motion with drift](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053294/density-of-first-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion-with-drift)