# Expectation of a stopping time containing BM

Tags: probability, expectation, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let (Bt)t≥0 be a standard Brownian Motion and let T := inf{t ≥ 0 : Bt = at − b} for some positive constants a, b > 0. Calculate E[T].

How can this be solved? By the optional stopping theorem?

Answer (score 1):

I am using different symbols than you are, so be careful when reading my answer. Let
$$
X_{t}^{\xi}=\xi t+W_{t}
$$
where $W$ is a Brownian motion. Let $a$ be a real number and
$$
\tau_{a\xi}=\inf\left\{ t\geq0\colon X_{t}^{\xi}=a\right\} 
$$
be the first hitting time the drifting Brownian motion reaches level
$a$. The density of $\tau_{a\xi}$ is
$$
f_{a\xi}(t)=\frac{\left|a\right|}{\sqrt{2\pi t^{3}}}\exp\left(-\frac{\left(a-\xi t\right)^{2}}{2t}\right).
$$
Then,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\tau_{a\xi}\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}tf_{a\xi}(t)dt=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\left|a\right|}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\exp\left(-\frac{\left(a-\xi t\right)^{2}}{2t}\right)dt=\frac{\left|a\right|}{\left|\xi\right|}e^{a\xi-\left|a\xi\right|}
$$
whenever $a\neq0$ or $\xi\neq0$.

Comment: Thank you. How can I get the density of $\tau_{\alpha\xi}$ ?

Comment: @koala: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053294/density-of-first-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion-with-drift