# First Passage Time distribution for a 2D Brownian particle with constant drift

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times, stochastic-differential-equations

Let's suppose we have an active Brownian particle whose overdamped equation of motion is given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = f + \sqrt{2D}\xi_x \\
\dot{y} = \sqrt{2D}\xi_y
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $f$ is a positive constant and $\xi_i$ is a Gaussian white noise delta-correlated in time with unit variance.
The particle starts at $(x_0,y_0)$ and has to reach a target located at $(x_1,y_0)$, with $x_1>x_0$. What is the First Passage Time distribution for this process?

I guess my question is kind of related to this one:

[Density of first hitting time of Brownian motion with drift](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053294/density-of-first-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion-with-drift)

where they find that the solution is an Inverse Gaussian distribution. Is it possible to generalize this result to the case I presented? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that points (and countable unions of points) are **polar** for Brownian motion in dimension greater than one. For example see [this paper](https://www.math-berlin.de/images/stories/lecnotes_moerters.pdf). The first time that your BM starting at $(x_0,x_0)$ will reach $(x_1,y_0)$ will therefore be infinite. The fact that a constant drift $f$ is added won't change the matters.